# BeautyTips bad stroke rendering

Tags: jquery, beautytips

I'm using BeautyTips the first time and set the plugin options like this:

```
$('.info').bt({
                width: 230,
                positions: 'right',
                fill: '#fff',
                cornerRadius: 0,
                strokeWidth: 3,
                strokeStyle: '#e95d0f',
                spikeLength: 9,
                spikeGirth: 17,
                overlap: -10,
                cssStyles: {
                    color: '#787887',
                    padding: '10px 15px'
                },
                hoverIntentOpts: {
                    interval: 200
                },
                showTip: function(tip) {
                    $(tip).fadeIn(400);
                },
                hideTip: function(tip) {
                    $(tip).fadeOut(200);
                }
            });
```

It should look like the following:

[image: tooltip correct]

But gets rendered like this:

[image: tooltip rendered wrong]

(top stroke is 2px instead of 3px and spike is cropped)

I have the latest version 0.9.5-rc1.
Does anyone know a fix for that?

Greets Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery 1.8 the curCSS() function has been removed. The following minified code uses css() instead.

```
jQuery.bt={version:"0.9.6"};(function($){jQuery.fn.bt=function(content,options){var contentSelect;if(typeof content!="string"){contentSelect=true;options=content;content=false}else{contentSelect=false}if(jQuery.fn.hoverIntent&&jQuery.bt.defaults.trigger=="hover"){jQuery.bt.defaults.trigger="hoverIntent"}return this.each(function(index){var opts=jQuery.extend(false,jQuery.bt.defaults,jQuery.bt.options,options);opts.spikeLength=numb(opts.spikeLength);opts.spikeGirth=numb(opts.spikeGirth);opts.overlap=numb(opts.overlap);var ajaxTimeout=false;if(opts.killTitle){$(this).find("[title]").andSelf().each(function(){if(!$(this).attr("bt-xTitle")){$(this).attr("bt-xTitle",$(this).attr("title")).attr("title","")}})}if(typeof opts.trigger=="string"){opts.trigger=[opts.trigger]}if(opts.trigger[0]=="hoverIntent"){var hoverOpts=jQuery.extend(opts.hoverIntentOpts,{over:function(){this.btOn()},out:function(){this.btOff()}});$(this).hoverIntent(hoverOpts)}else{if(opts.trigger[0]=="hover"){$(this).hover(function(){this.btOn()},function(){this.btOff()})}else{if(opts.trigger[0]=="now"){if($(this).hasClass("bt-active")){this.btOff()}else{this.btOn()}}else{if(opts.trigger[0]=="none"){}else{if(opts.trigger.length>1&&opts.trigger[0]!=opts.trigger[1]){$(this).bind(opts.trigger[0],function(){this.btOn()}).bind(opts.trigger[1],function(){this.btOff()})}else{$(this).bind(opts.trigger[0],function(){if($(this).hasClass("bt-active")){this.btOff()}else{this.btOn()}})}}}}}this.btOn=function(){if(typeof $(this).data("bt-box")=="object"){this.btOff()}opts.preBuild.apply(this);$(jQuery.bt.vars.closeWhenOpenStack).btOff();$(this).addClass("bt-active "+opts.activeClass);if(contentSelect&&opts.ajaxPath==null){if(opts.killTitle){$(this).attr("title",$(this).attr("bt-xTitle"))}content=$.isFunction(opts.contentSelector)?opts.contentSelector.apply(this):eval(opts.contentSelector);if(opts.killTitle){$(this).attr("title","")}}if(opts.ajaxPath!=null&&content==false){var url;if(typeof opts.ajaxPath=="object"){url=eval(opts.ajaxPath[0]);url+=opts.ajaxPath[1]?" "+opts.ajaxPath[1]:""}else{url=opts.ajaxPath}var off=url.indexOf(" ");if(off>=0){var selector=url.slice(off,url.length);url=url.slice(0,off)}var cacheData=opts.ajaxCache?$(document.body).data("btCache-"+url.replace(/\./g,"")):null;if(typeof cacheData=="string"){content=selector?$("<div/>").append(cacheData.replace(/<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/g,"")).find(selector):cacheData}else{var target=this;var ajaxOpts=jQuery.extend(false,{type:opts.ajaxType,data:opts.ajaxData,cache:opts.ajaxCache,url:url,complete:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus){if(textStatus=="success"||textStatus=="notmodified"){if(opts.ajaxCache){$(document.body).data("btCache-"+url.replace(/\./g,""),XMLHttpRequest.responseText)}ajaxTimeout=false;content=selector?$("<div/>").append(XMLHttpRequest.responseText.replace(/<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/g,"")).find(selector):XMLHttpRequest.responseText}else{if(textStatus=="timeout"){ajaxTimeout=true}content=opts.ajaxError.replace(/%error/g,XMLHttpRequest.statusText)}if($(target).hasClass("bt-active")){target.btOn()}}},opts.ajaxOpts);jQuery.ajax(ajaxOpts);content=opts.ajaxLoading}}var shadowMarginX=0;var shadowMarginY=0;var shadowShiftX=0;var shadowShiftY=0;if(opts.shadow&&!shadowSupport()){opts.shadow=false;jQuery.extend(opts,opts.noShadowOpts)}if(opts.shadow){if(opts.shadowBlur>Math.abs(opts.shadowOffsetX)){shadowMarginX=opts.shadowBlur*2}else{shadowMarginX=opts.shadowBlur+Math.abs(opts.shadowOffsetX)}shadowShiftX=(opts.shadowBlur-opts.shadowOffsetX)>0?opts.shadowBlur-opts.shadowOffsetX:0;if(opts.shadowBlur>Math.abs(opts.shadowOffsetY)){shadowMarginY=opts.shadowBlur*2}else{shadowMarginY=opts.shadowBlur+Math.abs(opts.shadowOffsetY)}shadowShiftY=(opts.shadowBlur-opts.shadowOffsetY)>0?opts.shadowBlur-opts.shadowOffsetY:0}var stroke=opts.strokeWidth/2,offsetParent,pos,top,left;if(opts.offsetParent){offsetParent=$(opts.offsetParent);var offsetParentPos=offsetParent.offset();pos=$(this).offset();top=numb(pos.top)-numb(offsetParentPos.top)+numb($(this).css("margin-top"))-shadowShiftY+stroke;left=numb(pos.left)-numb(offsetParentPos.left)+numb($(this).css("margin-left"))-shadowShiftX}else{offsetParent=($(this).css("position")=="absolute")?$(this).parents().eq(0).offsetParent():$(this).offsetParent();pos=$(this).btPosition();top=numb(pos.top)+numb($(this).css("margin-top"))-shadowShiftY+stroke;left=numb(pos.left)+numb($(this).css("margin-left"))-shadowShiftX}var width=$(this).btOuterWidth();var height=$(this).outerHeight();if(typeof content=="object"){var original=content;var clone=$(original).clone(true).show();var origClones=$(original).data("bt-clones")||[];origClones.push(clone);$(original).data("bt-clones",origClones);$(clone).data("bt-orig",original);$(this).data("bt-content-orig",{original:original,clone:clone});content=clone}if(typeof content=="null"||content==""){return}var $text=$('<div class="bt-content"></div>').append(content).css({padding:opts.padding,position:"absolute",width:(opts.shrinkToFit?"auto":opts.width),zIndex:opts.textzIndex,left:shadowShiftX,top:shadowShiftY}).css(opts.cssStyles);var $box=$('<div class="bt-wrapper"></div>').append($text).addClass(opts.cssClass).css({position:"absolute",width:opts.width,zIndex:opts.wrapperzIndex,visibility:"hidden"}).appendTo(offsetParent);if(jQuery.fn.bgiframe){$text.bgiframe();$box.bgiframe()}$(this).data("bt-box",$box);var scrollTop=numb($(document).scrollTop()),scrollLeft=numb($(document).scrollLeft()),docWidth=numb($(window).width()),docHeight=numb($(window).height()),winRight=scrollLeft+docWidth,winBottom=scrollTop+docHeight,space=new Object(),thisOffset=$(this).offset(),position;space.top=thisOffset.top-scrollTop;space.bottom=docHeight-((thisOffset+height)-scrollTop);space.left=thisOffset.left-scrollLeft;space.right=docWidth-((thisOffset.left+width)-scrollLeft);var textOutHeight=numb($text.outerHeight());var textOutWidth=numb($text.btOuterWidth());if(opts.positions.constructor==String){opts.positions=opts.positions.replace(/ /,"").split(",")}if(opts.positions[0]=="most"){position="top";for(var pig in space){position=space[pig]>space[position]?pig:position}}else{for(var x in opts.positions){position=opts.positions[x];if((position=="left"||position=="right")&&space[position]>textOutWidth+opts.spikeLength){break}else{if((position=="top"||position=="bottom")&&space[position]>textOutHeight+opts.spikeLength){break}}}}var horiz=left+((width-textOutWidth)*0.5),vert=top+((height-textOutHeight)*0.5),points=new Array(),textTop,textLeft,textRight,textBottom,textCenter,textTopSpace,textBottomSpace,textLeftSpace,textRightSpace,crossPoint,spikePoint,xShift,yShift;switch(position){case"top":$text.css("margin-bottom",opts.spikeLength+"px");$box.css({top:(top-$text.outerHeight(true))+opts.overlap,left:horiz});textRightSpace=(winRight-opts.windowMargin)-($text.offset().left+$text.btOuterWidth(true));xShift=shadowShiftX+stroke;if(textRightSpace<0){$box.css("left",(numb($box.css("left"))+textRightSpace)+"px");xShift-=textRightSpace}textLeftSpace=($text.offset().left+numb($text.css("margin-left")))-(scrollLeft+opts.windowMargin);if(textLeftSpace<0){$box.css("left",(numb($box.css("left"))-textLeftSpace)+"px");xShift+=textLeftSpace}textTop=$text.btPosition().top+numb($text.css("margin-top"))+stroke;textLeft=$text.btPosition().left+numb($text.css("margin-left"))+Math.ceil(stroke);textRight=round5(textLeft+$text.btOuterWidth(),stroke);textBottom=round5(textTop+$text.outerHeight(),stroke);textCenter={x:textLeft+($text.btOuterWidth()*opts.centerPointX),y:textTop+($text.outerHeight()*opts.centerPointY)};points[points.length]=spikePoint={y:textBottom+opts.spikeLength,x:((textRight-textLeft)*0.5)+xShift,type:"spike"};crossPoint=findIntersectX(spikePoint.x,spikePoint.y,textCenter.x,textCenter.y,textBottom);crossPoint.x=crossPoint.x<textLeft+opts.spikeGirth/2+opts.cornerRadius?textLeft+opts.spikeGirth/2+opts.cornerRadius:crossPoint.x;crossPoint.x=crossPoint.x>(textRight-opts.spikeGirth/2)-opts.cornerRadius?(textRight-opts.spikeGirth/2)-opts.CornerRadius:crossPoint.x;points[points.length]={x:crossPoint.x-(opts.spikeGirth/2),y:textBottom,type:"join"};points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:textBottom,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:textTop,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:textTop,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:textBottom,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:crossPoint.x+(opts.spikeGirth/2),y:textBottom,type:"join"};break;case"left":$text.css("margin-right",opts.spikeLength+"px");$box.css({top:vert+"px",left:((left-$text.btOuterWidth(true))+opts.overlap)+"px"});textBottomSpace=(winBottom-opts.windowMargin)-($text.offset().top+$text.outerHeight(true));yShift=shadowShiftY+stroke;if(textBottomSpace<0){$box.css("top",(numb($box.css("top"))+textBottomSpace)+"px");yShift-=textBottomSpace}textTopSpace=($text.offset().top+numb($text.css("margin-top")))-(scrollTop+opts.windowMargin);if(textTopSpace<0){$box.css("top",(numb($box.css("top"))-textTopSpace)+"px");yShift+=textTopSpace}textTop=$text.btPosition().top+numb($text.css("margin-top"))+stroke;textLeft=$text.btPosition().left+numb($text.css("margin-left"))+Math.ceil(stroke);textRight=round5(textLeft+$text.btOuterWidth(),stroke);textBottom=round5(textTop+$text.outerHeight(),stroke);textCenter={x:textLeft+($text.btOuterWidth()*opts.centerPointX),y:textTop+($text.outerHeight()*opts.centerPointY)};points[points.length]=spikePoint={x:textRight+opts.spikeLength,y:((textBottom-textTop)*0.5)+yShift,type:"spike"};crossPoint=findIntersectY(spikePoint.x,spikePoint.y,textCenter.x,textCenter.y,textRight);crossPoint.y=crossPoint.y<textTop+opts.spikeGirth/2+opts.cornerRadius?textTop+opts.spikeGirth/2+opts.cornerRadius:crossPoint.y;crossPoint.y=crossPoint.y>(textBottom-opts.spikeGirth/2)-opts.cornerRadius?(textBottom-opts.spikeGirth/2)-opts.cornerRadius:crossPoint.y;points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:crossPoint.y+opts.spikeGirth/2,type:"join"};points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:textBottom,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:textBottom,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:textTop,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:textTop,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:crossPoint.y-opts.spikeGirth/2,type:"join"};break;case"bottom":$text.css("margin-top",opts.spikeLength+"px");$box.css({top:(top+height)-opts.overlap,left:horiz});textRightSpace=(winRight-opts.windowMargin)-($text.offset().left+$text.btOuterWidth(true));xShift=shadowShiftX+stroke;if(textRightSpace<0){$box.css("left",(numb($box.css("left"))+textRightSpace)+"px");xShift-=textRightSpace}textLeftSpace=($text.offset().left+numb($text.css("margin-left")))-(scrollLeft+opts.windowMargin);if(textLeftSpace<0){$box.css("left",(numb($box.css("left"))-textLeftSpace)+"px");xShift+=textLeftSpace}textTop=$text.btPosition().top+numb($text.css("margin-top"))+stroke;textLeft=$text.btPosition().left+numb($text.css("margin-left"))+Math.ceil(stroke);textRight=round5(textLeft+$text.btOuterWidth(),stroke);textBottom=round5(textTop+$text.outerHeight(),stroke);textCenter={x:textLeft+($text.btOuterWidth()*opts.centerPointX),y:textTop+($text.outerHeight()*opts.centerPointY)};points[points.length]=spikePoint={x:((textRight-textLeft)*0.5)+xShift,y:shadowShiftY,type:"spike"};crossPoint=findIntersectX(spikePoint.x,spikePoint.y,textCenter.x,textCenter.y,textTop);crossPoint.x=crossPoint.x<textLeft+opts.spikeGirth/2+opts.cornerRadius?textLeft+opts.spikeGirth/2+opts.cornerRadius:crossPoint.x;crossPoint.x=crossPoint.x>(textRight-opts.spikeGirth/2)-opts.cornerRadius?(textRight-opts.spikeGirth/2)-opts.cornerRadius:crossPoint.x;points[points.length]={x:crossPoint.x+opts.spikeGirth/2,y:textTop,type:"join"};points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:textTop,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:textBottom,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:textBottom,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:textTop,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:crossPoint.x-(opts.spikeGirth/2),y:textTop,type:"join"};break;case"right":$text.css("margin-left",(opts.spikeLength+stroke+"px"));$box.css({top:vert+"px",left:((left+width)-opts.overlap)+"px"});textBottomSpace=(winBottom-opts.windowMargin)-($text.offset().top+$text.outerHeight(true));yShift=shadowShiftY+stroke;if(textBottomSpace<0){$box.css("top",(numb($box.css("top"))+textBottomSpace)+"px");yShift-=textBottomSpace}textTopSpace=($text.offset().top+numb($text.css("margin-top")))-(scrollTop+opts.windowMargin);if(textTopSpace<0){$box.css("top",(numb($box.css("top"))-textTopSpace)+"px");yShift+=textTopSpace}textTop=$text.btPosition().top+numb($text.css("margin-top"))+stroke;textLeft=$text.btPosition().left+numb($text.css("margin-left"))+Math.ceil(stroke);textRight=round5(textLeft+$text.btOuterWidth(),stroke);textBottom=round5(textTop+$text.outerHeight(),stroke);textCenter={x:textLeft+($text.btOuterWidth()*opts.centerPointX),y:textTop+($text.outerHeight()*opts.centerPointY)};points[points.length]=spikePoint={x:shadowShiftX+stroke,y:((textBottom-textTop)*0.5)+yShift,type:"spike"};crossPoint=findIntersectY(spikePoint.x,spikePoint.y,textCenter.x,textCenter.y,textLeft);crossPoint.y=crossPoint.y<textTop+opts.spikeGirth/2+opts.cornerRadius?textTop+opts.spikeGirth/2+opts.cornerRadius:crossPoint.y;crossPoint.y=crossPoint.y>(textBottom-opts.spikeGirth/2)-opts.cornerRadius?(textBottom-opts.spikeGirth/2)-opts.cornerRadius:crossPoint.y;points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:crossPoint.y-opts.spikeGirth/2,type:"join"};points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:textTop,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:textTop,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:textBottom,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:textBottom,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:crossPoint.y+opts.spikeGirth/2,type:"join"};break}points[points.length]=spikePoint;var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");$(canvas).attr("width",(numb($text.btOuterWidth(true))+opts.strokeWidth*2+shadowMarginX)).attr("height",(numb($text.outerHeight(true))+opts.strokeWidth*2+shadowMarginY)).appendTo($box).css({position:"absolute",top:-stroke,left:-stroke,zIndex:opts.boxzIndex});if(typeof G_vmlCanvasManager!="undefined"){canvas=G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas)}if(opts.cornerRadius>0){var newPoints=new Array();var newPoint;for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){if(points[i].type=="corner"){newPoint=betweenPoint(points[i],points[(i-1)%points.length],opts.cornerRadius);newPoint.type="arcStart";newPoints[newPoints.length]=newPoint;newPoints[newPoints.length]=points[i];newPoint=betweenPoint(points[i],points[(i+1)%points.length],opts.cornerRadius);newPoint.type="arcEnd";newPoints[newPoints.length]=newPoint}else{newPoints[newPoints.length]=points[i]}}points=newPoints}var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");if(opts.shadow&&opts.shadowOverlap!==true){var shadowOverlap=numb(opts.shadowOverlap);switch(position){case"top":if(opts.shadowOffsetX+opts.shadowBlur-shadowOverlap>0){$box.css("top",(numb($box.css("top"))-(opts.shadowOffsetX+opts.shadowBlur-shadowOverlap)))}break;case"right":if(shadowShiftX-shadowOverlap>0){$box.css("left",(numb($box.css("left"))+shadowShiftX-shadowOverlap))}break;case"bottom":if(shadowShiftY-shadowOverlap>0){$box.css("top",(numb($box.css("top"))+shadowShiftY-shadowOverlap))}break;case"left":if(opts.shadowOffsetY+opts.shadowBlur-shadowOverlap>0){$box.css("left",(numb($box.css("left"))-(opts.shadowOffsetY+opts.shadowBlur-shadowOverlap)))}break}}drawIt.apply(ctx,[points]);ctx.fillStyle=opts.fill;if(opts.shadow){ctx.shadowOffsetX=opts.shadowOffsetX;ctx.shadowOffsetY=opts.shadowOffsetY;ctx.shadowBlur=opts.shadowBlur;ctx.shadowColor=opts.shadowColor}ctx.closePath();ctx.fill();if(opts.strokeWidth>0){ctx.shadowColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)";ctx.lineWidth=opts.strokeWidth;ctx.strokeStyle=opts.strokeStyle;ctx.beginPath();drawIt.apply(ctx,[points]);ctx.closePath();ctx.stroke()}opts.preShow.apply(this,[$box[0]]);$box.css({display:"none",visibility:"visible"});opts.showTip.apply(this,[$box[0]]);if(opts.overlay){var overlay=$('<div class="bt-overlay"></div>').css({position:"absolute",backgroundColor:"blue",top:top,left:left,width:width,height:height,opacity:".2"}).appendTo(offsetParent);$(this).data("overlay",overlay)}if((opts.ajaxPath!=null&&opts.ajaxCache==false)||ajaxTimeout){content=false}if(opts.clickAnywhereToClose){jQuery.bt.vars.clickAnywhereStack.push(this);$(document).click(jQuery.bt.docClick)}if(opts.closeWhenOthersOpen){jQuery.bt.vars.closeWhenOpenStack.push(this)}opts.postShow.apply(this,[$box[0]])};this.btOff=function(){var box=$(this).data("bt-box");opts.preHide.apply(this,[box]);var i=this;i.btCleanup=function(){var box=$(i).data("bt-box");var contentOrig=$(i).data("bt-content-orig");var overlay=$(i).data("bt-overlay");if(typeof box=="object"){$(box).remove();$(i).removeData("bt-box")}if(typeof contentOrig=="object"){var clones=$(contentOrig.original).data("bt-clones");$(contentOrig).data("bt-clones",arrayRemove(clones,contentOrig.clone))}if(typeof overlay=="object"){$(overlay).remove();$(i).removeData("bt-overlay")}jQuery.bt.vars.clickAnywhereStack=arrayRemove(jQuery.bt.vars.clickAnywhereStack,i);jQuery.bt.vars.closeWhenOpenStack=arrayRemove(jQuery.bt.vars.closeWhenOpenStack,i);$(i).removeClass("bt-active "+opts.activeClass);opts.postHide.apply(i)};opts.hideTip.apply(this,[box,i.btCleanup])};var refresh=this.btRefresh=function(){this.btOff();this.btOn()}});function drawIt(points){var strokeWidth=jQuery.bt.options.strokeWidth?jQuery.bt.options.strokeWidth:jQuery.bt.defaults.strokeWidth;this.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);for(i=1;i<points.length;i++){if(points[i-1].type=="arcStart"){this.quadraticCurveTo(round5(points[i].x,strokeWidth),round5(points[i].y,strokeWidth),round5(points[(i+1)%points.length].x,strokeWidth),round5(points[(i+1)%points.length].y,strokeWidth));i++}else{this.lineTo(round5(points[i].x,strokeWidth),round5(points[i].y,strokeWidth))}}}function round5(num,strokeWidth){var ret=num;strokeWidth=numb(strokeWidth);if(!(strokeWidth%2)){ret=Math.round(num-0.5)+0.5}return ret}function numb(num){return parseInt(num)||0}function arrayRemove(arr,elem){var x,newArr=new Array();for(x in arr){if(arr[x]!=elem){newArr.push(arr[x])}}return newArr}function shadowSupport(){try{var userAgent=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();if(/webkit/.test(userAgent)){return true}else{if(/gecko|mozilla/.test(userAgent)&&parseFloat(userAgent.match(/firefox\/(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)/)[1])>=3.1){return true}}}catch(err){}return false}function betweenPoint(point1,point2,dist){var y,x;if(point1.x==point2.x){y=point1.y<point2.y?point1.y+dist:point1.y-dist;return{x:point1.x,y:y}}else{if(point1.y==point2.y){x=point1.x<point2.x?point1.x+dist:point1.x-dist;return{x:x,y:point1.y}}}return false}function findIntersect(r1x1,r1y1,r1x2,r1y2,r2x1,r2y1,r2x2,r2y2){if(r2x1==r2x2){return findIntersectY(r1x1,r1y1,r1x2,r1y2,r2x1)}if(r2y1==r2y2){return findIntersectX(r1x1,r1y1,r1x2,r1y2,r2y1)}var r1m=(r1y1-r1y2)/(r1x1-r1x2);var r1b=r1y1-(r1m*r1x1);var r2m=(r2y1-r2y2)/(r2x1-r2x2);var r2b=r2y1-(r2m*r2x1);var x=(r2b-r1b)/(r1m-r2m);var y=r1m*x+r1b;return{x:x,y:y}}function findIntersectY(r1x1,r1y1,r1x2,r1y2,x){if(r1y1==r1y2){return{x:x,y:r1y1}}var r1m=(r1y1-r1y2)/(r1x1-r1x2);var r1b=r1y1-(r1m*r1x1);var y=r1m*x+r1b;return{x:x,y:y}}function findIntersectX(r1x1,r1y1,r1x2,r1y2,y){if(r1x1==r1x2){return{x:r1x1,y:y}}var r1m=(r1y1-r1y2)/(r1x1-r1x2);var r1b=r1y1-(r1m*r1x1);var x=(y-r1b)/r1m;return{x:x,y:y}}};jQuery.fn.btPosition=function(){function num(elem,prop){return elem[0]&&parseInt(jQuery.css(elem[0],prop,true),10)||0}var left=0,top=0,results;if(this[0]){var offsetParent=this.offsetParent(),offset=this.offset(),parentOffset=/^body|html$/i.test(offsetParent[0].tagName)?{top:0,left:0}:offsetParent.offset();offset.top-=num(this,"marginTop");offset.left-=num(this,"marginLeft");parentOffset.top+=num(offsetParent,"borderTopWidth");parentOffset.left+=num(offsetParent,"borderLeftWidth");results={top:offset.top-parentOffset.top,left:offset.left-parentOffset.left}}return results};jQuery.fn.btOuterWidth=function(margin){function num(elem,prop){return elem[0]&&parseInt(jQuery.css(elem[0],prop,true),10)||0}return this["innerWidth"]()+num(this,"borderLeftWidth")+num(this,"borderRightWidth")+(margin?num(this,"marginLeft")+num(this,"marginRight"):0)};jQuery.fn.btOn=function(){return this.each(function(index){if(jQuery.isFunction(this.btOn)){this.btOn()}})};jQuery.fn.btOff=function(){return this.each(function(index){if(jQuery.isFunction(this.btOff)){this.btOff()}})};jQuery.bt.vars={clickAnywhereStack:[],closeWhenOpenStack:[]};jQuery.bt.docClick=function(e){if(!e){var e=window.event}if(!$(e.target).parents().andSelf().filter(".bt-wrapper, .bt-active").length&&jQuery.bt.vars.clickAnywhereStack.length){$(jQuery.bt.vars.clickAnywhereStack).btOff();$(document).unbind("click",jQuery.bt.docClick)}};jQuery.bt.defaults={trigger:"hover",clickAnywhereToClose:true,closeWhenOthersOpen:false,shrinkToFit:false,width:"200px",padding:"10px",spikeGirth:10,spikeLength:15,overlap:0,overlay:false,killTitle:true,textzIndex:9999,boxzIndex:9998,wrapperzIndex:9997,offsetParent:null,positions:["most"],fill:"rgb(255, 255, 102)",windowMargin:10,strokeWidth:1,strokeStyle:"#000",cornerRadius:5,centerPointX:0.5,centerPointY:0.5,shadow:false,shadowOffsetX:2,shadowOffsetY:2,shadowBlur:3,shadowColor:"#000",shadowOverlap:false,noShadowOpts:{strokeStyle:"#999"},cssClass:"",cssStyles:{},activeClass:"bt-active",contentSelector:"$(this).attr('title')",ajaxPath:null,ajaxError:"<strong>ERROR:</strong> <em>%error</em>",ajaxLoading:"<blink>Loading...</blink>",ajaxData:{},ajaxType:"GET",ajaxCache:true,ajaxOpts:{},preBuild:function(){},preShow:function(box){},showTip:function(box){$(box).show()},postShow:function(box){},preHide:function(box){},hideTip:function(box,callback){$(box).hide();callback()},postHide:function(){},hoverIntentOpts:{interval:300,timeout:500}};jQuery.bt.options={}})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that the plugin hasn't been updated in 4 years now I debugged it myself, I also commented some functions out which weren't even in use so it minifies better.

Here the minified code, if someone wants to use it:

```
jQuery.bt={version:"0.9.6"};(function($){jQuery.fn.bt=function(content,options){var contentSelect;if(typeof content!="string"){contentSelect=true;options=content;content=false}else{contentSelect=false}if(jQuery.fn.hoverIntent&&jQuery.bt.defaults.trigger=="hover"){jQuery.bt.defaults.trigger="hoverIntent"}return this.each(function(index){var opts=jQuery.extend(false,jQuery.bt.defaults,jQuery.bt.options,options);opts.spikeLength=numb(opts.spikeLength);opts.spikeGirth=numb(opts.spikeGirth);opts.overlap=numb(opts.overlap);var ajaxTimeout=false;if(opts.killTitle){$(this).find("[title]").andSelf().each(function(){if(!$(this).attr("bt-xTitle")){$(this).attr("bt-xTitle",$(this).attr("title")).attr("title","")}})}if(typeof opts.trigger=="string"){opts.trigger=[opts.trigger]}if(opts.trigger[0]=="hoverIntent"){var hoverOpts=jQuery.extend(opts.hoverIntentOpts,{over:function(){this.btOn()},out:function(){this.btOff()}});$(this).hoverIntent(hoverOpts)}else{if(opts.trigger[0]=="hover"){$(this).hover(function(){this.btOn()},function(){this.btOff()})}else{if(opts.trigger[0]=="now"){if($(this).hasClass("bt-active")){this.btOff()}else{this.btOn()}}else{if(opts.trigger[0]=="none"){}else{if(opts.trigger.length>1&&opts.trigger[0]!=opts.trigger[1]){$(this).bind(opts.trigger[0],function(){this.btOn()}).bind(opts.trigger[1],function(){this.btOff()})}else{$(this).bind(opts.trigger[0],function(){if($(this).hasClass("bt-active")){this.btOff()}else{this.btOn()}})}}}}}this.btOn=function(){if(typeof $(this).data("bt-box")=="object"){this.btOff()}opts.preBuild.apply(this);$(jQuery.bt.vars.closeWhenOpenStack).btOff();$(this).addClass("bt-active "+opts.activeClass);if(contentSelect&&opts.ajaxPath==null){if(opts.killTitle){$(this).attr("title",$(this).attr("bt-xTitle"))}content=$.isFunction(opts.contentSelector)?opts.contentSelector.apply(this):eval(opts.contentSelector);if(opts.killTitle){$(this).attr("title","")}}if(opts.ajaxPath!=null&&content==false){var url;if(typeof opts.ajaxPath=="object"){url=eval(opts.ajaxPath[0]);url+=opts.ajaxPath[1]?" "+opts.ajaxPath[1]:""}else{url=opts.ajaxPath}var off=url.indexOf(" ");if(off>=0){var selector=url.slice(off,url.length);url=url.slice(0,off)}var cacheData=opts.ajaxCache?$(document.body).data("btCache-"+url.replace(/\./g,"")):null;if(typeof cacheData=="string"){content=selector?$("<div/>").append(cacheData.replace(/<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/g,"")).find(selector):cacheData}else{var target=this;var ajaxOpts=jQuery.extend(false,{type:opts.ajaxType,data:opts.ajaxData,cache:opts.ajaxCache,url:url,complete:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus){if(textStatus=="success"||textStatus=="notmodified"){if(opts.ajaxCache){$(document.body).data("btCache-"+url.replace(/\./g,""),XMLHttpRequest.responseText)}ajaxTimeout=false;content=selector?$("<div/>").append(XMLHttpRequest.responseText.replace(/<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/g,"")).find(selector):XMLHttpRequest.responseText}else{if(textStatus=="timeout"){ajaxTimeout=true}content=opts.ajaxError.replace(/%error/g,XMLHttpRequest.statusText)}if($(target).hasClass("bt-active")){target.btOn()}}},opts.ajaxOpts);jQuery.ajax(ajaxOpts);content=opts.ajaxLoading}}var shadowMarginX=0;var shadowMarginY=0;var shadowShiftX=0;var shadowShiftY=0;if(opts.shadow&&!shadowSupport()){opts.shadow=false;jQuery.extend(opts,opts.noShadowOpts)}if(opts.shadow){if(opts.shadowBlur>Math.abs(opts.shadowOffsetX)){shadowMarginX=opts.shadowBlur*2}else{shadowMarginX=opts.shadowBlur+Math.abs(opts.shadowOffsetX)}shadowShiftX=(opts.shadowBlur-opts.shadowOffsetX)>0?opts.shadowBlur-opts.shadowOffsetX:0;if(opts.shadowBlur>Math.abs(opts.shadowOffsetY)){shadowMarginY=opts.shadowBlur*2}else{shadowMarginY=opts.shadowBlur+Math.abs(opts.shadowOffsetY)}shadowShiftY=(opts.shadowBlur-opts.shadowOffsetY)>0?opts.shadowBlur-opts.shadowOffsetY:0}var stroke=opts.strokeWidth/2,offsetParent,pos,top,left;if(opts.offsetParent){offsetParent=$(opts.offsetParent);var offsetParentPos=offsetParent.offset();pos=$(this).offset();top=numb(pos.top)-numb(offsetParentPos.top)+numb($(this).css("margin-top"))-shadowShiftY+stroke;left=numb(pos.left)-numb(offsetParentPos.left)+numb($(this).css("margin-left"))-shadowShiftX}else{offsetParent=($(this).css("position")=="absolute")?$(this).parents().eq(0).offsetParent():$(this).offsetParent();pos=$(this).btPosition();top=numb(pos.top)+numb($(this).css("margin-top"))-shadowShiftY+stroke;left=numb(pos.left)+numb($(this).css("margin-left"))-shadowShiftX}var width=$(this).btOuterWidth();var height=$(this).outerHeight();if(typeof content=="object"){var original=content;var clone=$(original).clone(true).show();var origClones=$(original).data("bt-clones")||[];origClones.push(clone);$(original).data("bt-clones",origClones);$(clone).data("bt-orig",original);$(this).data("bt-content-orig",{original:original,clone:clone});content=clone}if(typeof content=="null"||content==""){return}var $text=$('<div class="bt-content"></div>').append(content).css({padding:opts.padding,position:"absolute",width:(opts.shrinkToFit?"auto":opts.width),zIndex:opts.textzIndex,left:shadowShiftX,top:shadowShiftY}).css(opts.cssStyles);var $box=$('<div class="bt-wrapper"></div>').append($text).addClass(opts.cssClass).css({position:"absolute",width:opts.width,zIndex:opts.wrapperzIndex,visibility:"hidden"}).appendTo(offsetParent);if(jQuery.fn.bgiframe){$text.bgiframe();$box.bgiframe()}$(this).data("bt-box",$box);var scrollTop=numb($(document).scrollTop()),scrollLeft=numb($(document).scrollLeft()),docWidth=numb($(window).width()),docHeight=numb($(window).height()),winRight=scrollLeft+docWidth,winBottom=scrollTop+docHeight,space=new Object(),thisOffset=$(this).offset(),position;space.top=thisOffset.top-scrollTop;space.bottom=docHeight-((thisOffset+height)-scrollTop);space.left=thisOffset.left-scrollLeft;space.right=docWidth-((thisOffset.left+width)-scrollLeft);var textOutHeight=numb($text.outerHeight());var textOutWidth=numb($text.btOuterWidth());if(opts.positions.constructor==String){opts.positions=opts.positions.replace(/ /,"").split(",")}if(opts.positions[0]=="most"){position="top";for(var pig in space){position=space[pig]>space[position]?pig:position}}else{for(var x in opts.positions){position=opts.positions[x];if((position=="left"||position=="right")&&space[position]>textOutWidth+opts.spikeLength){break}else{if((position=="top"||position=="bottom")&&space[position]>textOutHeight+opts.spikeLength){break}}}}var horiz=left+((width-textOutWidth)*0.5),vert=top+((height-textOutHeight)*0.5),points=new Array(),textTop,textLeft,textRight,textBottom,textCenter,textTopSpace,textBottomSpace,textLeftSpace,textRightSpace,crossPoint,spikePoint,xShift,yShift;switch(position){case"top":$text.css("margin-bottom",opts.spikeLength+"px");$box.css({top:(top-$text.outerHeight(true))+opts.overlap,left:horiz});textRightSpace=(winRight-opts.windowMargin)-($text.offset().left+$text.btOuterWidth(true));xShift=shadowShiftX+stroke;if(textRightSpace<0){$box.css("left",(numb($box.css("left"))+textRightSpace)+"px");xShift-=textRightSpace}textLeftSpace=($text.offset().left+numb($text.css("margin-left")))-(scrollLeft+opts.windowMargin);if(textLeftSpace<0){$box.css("left",(numb($box.css("left"))-textLeftSpace)+"px");xShift+=textLeftSpace}textTop=$text.btPosition().top+numb($text.css("margin-top"))+stroke;textLeft=$text.btPosition().left+numb($text.css("margin-left"))+Math.ceil(stroke);textRight=round5(textLeft+$text.btOuterWidth(),stroke);textBottom=round5(textTop+$text.outerHeight(),stroke);textCenter={x:textLeft+($text.btOuterWidth()*opts.centerPointX),y:textTop+($text.outerHeight()*opts.centerPointY)};points[points.length]=spikePoint={y:textBottom+opts.spikeLength,x:((textRight-textLeft)*0.5)+xShift,type:"spike"};crossPoint=findIntersectX(spikePoint.x,spikePoint.y,textCenter.x,textCenter.y,textBottom);crossPoint.x=crossPoint.x<textLeft+opts.spikeGirth/2+opts.cornerRadius?textLeft+opts.spikeGirth/2+opts.cornerRadius:crossPoint.x;crossPoint.x=crossPoint.x>(textRight-opts.spikeGirth/2)-opts.cornerRadius?(textRight-opts.spikeGirth/2)-opts.CornerRadius:crossPoint.x;points[points.length]={x:crossPoint.x-(opts.spikeGirth/2),y:textBottom,type:"join"};points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:textBottom,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:textTop,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:textTop,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:textBottom,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:crossPoint.x+(opts.spikeGirth/2),y:textBottom,type:"join"};break;case"left":$text.css("margin-right",opts.spikeLength+"px");$box.css({top:vert+"px",left:((left-$text.btOuterWidth(true))+opts.overlap)+"px"});textBottomSpace=(winBottom-opts.windowMargin)-($text.offset().top+$text.outerHeight(true));yShift=shadowShiftY+stroke;if(textBottomSpace<0){$box.css("top",(numb($box.css("top"))+textBottomSpace)+"px");yShift-=textBottomSpace}textTopSpace=($text.offset().top+numb($text.css("margin-top")))-(scrollTop+opts.windowMargin);if(textTopSpace<0){$box.css("top",(numb($box.css("top"))-textTopSpace)+"px");yShift+=textTopSpace}textTop=$text.btPosition().top+numb($text.css("margin-top"))+stroke;textLeft=$text.btPosition().left+numb($text.css("margin-left"))+Math.ceil(stroke);textRight=round5(textLeft+$text.btOuterWidth(),stroke);textBottom=round5(textTop+$text.outerHeight(),stroke);textCenter={x:textLeft+($text.btOuterWidth()*opts.centerPointX),y:textTop+($text.outerHeight()*opts.centerPointY)};points[points.length]=spikePoint={x:textRight+opts.spikeLength,y:((textBottom-textTop)*0.5)+yShift,type:"spike"};crossPoint=findIntersectY(spikePoint.x,spikePoint.y,textCenter.x,textCenter.y,textRight);crossPoint.y=crossPoint.y<textTop+opts.spikeGirth/2+opts.cornerRadius?textTop+opts.spikeGirth/2+opts.cornerRadius:crossPoint.y;crossPoint.y=crossPoint.y>(textBottom-opts.spikeGirth/2)-opts.cornerRadius?(textBottom-opts.spikeGirth/2)-opts.cornerRadius:crossPoint.y;points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:crossPoint.y+opts.spikeGirth/2,type:"join"};points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:textBottom,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:textBottom,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:textTop,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:textTop,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:crossPoint.y-opts.spikeGirth/2,type:"join"};break;case"bottom":$text.css("margin-top",opts.spikeLength+"px");$box.css({top:(top+height)-opts.overlap,left:horiz});textRightSpace=(winRight-opts.windowMargin)-($text.offset().left+$text.btOuterWidth(true));xShift=shadowShiftX+stroke;if(textRightSpace<0){$box.css("left",(numb($box.css("left"))+textRightSpace)+"px");xShift-=textRightSpace}textLeftSpace=($text.offset().left+numb($text.css("margin-left")))-(scrollLeft+opts.windowMargin);if(textLeftSpace<0){$box.css("left",(numb($box.css("left"))-textLeftSpace)+"px");xShift+=textLeftSpace}textTop=$text.btPosition().top+numb($text.css("margin-top"))+stroke;textLeft=$text.btPosition().left+numb($text.css("margin-left"))+Math.ceil(stroke);textRight=round5(textLeft+$text.btOuterWidth(),stroke);textBottom=round5(textTop+$text.outerHeight(),stroke);textCenter={x:textLeft+($text.btOuterWidth()*opts.centerPointX),y:textTop+($text.outerHeight()*opts.centerPointY)};points[points.length]=spikePoint={x:((textRight-textLeft)*0.5)+xShift,y:shadowShiftY,type:"spike"};crossPoint=findIntersectX(spikePoint.x,spikePoint.y,textCenter.x,textCenter.y,textTop);crossPoint.x=crossPoint.x<textLeft+opts.spikeGirth/2+opts.cornerRadius?textLeft+opts.spikeGirth/2+opts.cornerRadius:crossPoint.x;crossPoint.x=crossPoint.x>(textRight-opts.spikeGirth/2)-opts.cornerRadius?(textRight-opts.spikeGirth/2)-opts.cornerRadius:crossPoint.x;points[points.length]={x:crossPoint.x+opts.spikeGirth/2,y:textTop,type:"join"};points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:textTop,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:textBottom,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:textBottom,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:textTop,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:crossPoint.x-(opts.spikeGirth/2),y:textTop,type:"join"};break;case"right":$text.css("margin-left",(opts.spikeLength+stroke+"px"));$box.css({top:vert+"px",left:((left+width)-opts.overlap)+"px"});textBottomSpace=(winBottom-opts.windowMargin)-($text.offset().top+$text.outerHeight(true));yShift=shadowShiftY+stroke;if(textBottomSpace<0){$box.css("top",(numb($box.css("top"))+textBottomSpace)+"px");yShift-=textBottomSpace}textTopSpace=($text.offset().top+numb($text.css("margin-top")))-(scrollTop+opts.windowMargin);if(textTopSpace<0){$box.css("top",(numb($box.css("top"))-textTopSpace)+"px");yShift+=textTopSpace}textTop=$text.btPosition().top+numb($text.css("margin-top"))+stroke;textLeft=$text.btPosition().left+numb($text.css("margin-left"))+Math.ceil(stroke);textRight=round5(textLeft+$text.btOuterWidth(),stroke);textBottom=round5(textTop+$text.outerHeight(),stroke);textCenter={x:textLeft+($text.btOuterWidth()*opts.centerPointX),y:textTop+($text.outerHeight()*opts.centerPointY)};points[points.length]=spikePoint={x:shadowShiftX+stroke,y:((textBottom-textTop)*0.5)+yShift,type:"spike"};crossPoint=findIntersectY(spikePoint.x,spikePoint.y,textCenter.x,textCenter.y,textLeft);crossPoint.y=crossPoint.y<textTop+opts.spikeGirth/2+opts.cornerRadius?textTop+opts.spikeGirth/2+opts.cornerRadius:crossPoint.y;crossPoint.y=crossPoint.y>(textBottom-opts.spikeGirth/2)-opts.cornerRadius?(textBottom-opts.spikeGirth/2)-opts.cornerRadius:crossPoint.y;points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:crossPoint.y-opts.spikeGirth/2,type:"join"};points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:textTop,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:textTop,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textRight,y:textBottom,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:textBottom,type:"corner"};points[points.length]={x:textLeft,y:crossPoint.y+opts.spikeGirth/2,type:"join"};break}points[points.length]=spikePoint;var canvas=document.createElement("canvas");$(canvas).attr("width",(numb($text.btOuterWidth(true))+opts.strokeWidth*2+shadowMarginX)).attr("height",(numb($text.outerHeight(true))+opts.strokeWidth*2+shadowMarginY)).appendTo($box).css({position:"absolute",top:-stroke,left:-stroke,zIndex:opts.boxzIndex});if(typeof G_vmlCanvasManager!="undefined"){canvas=G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas)}if(opts.cornerRadius>0){var newPoints=new Array();var newPoint;for(var i=0;i<points.length;i++){if(points[i].type=="corner"){newPoint=betweenPoint(points[i],points[(i-1)%points.length],opts.cornerRadius);newPoint.type="arcStart";newPoints[newPoints.length]=newPoint;newPoints[newPoints.length]=points[i];newPoint=betweenPoint(points[i],points[(i+1)%points.length],opts.cornerRadius);newPoint.type="arcEnd";newPoints[newPoints.length]=newPoint}else{newPoints[newPoints.length]=points[i]}}points=newPoints}var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");if(opts.shadow&&opts.shadowOverlap!==true){var shadowOverlap=numb(opts.shadowOverlap);switch(position){case"top":if(opts.shadowOffsetX+opts.shadowBlur-shadowOverlap>0){$box.css("top",(numb($box.css("top"))-(opts.shadowOffsetX+opts.shadowBlur-shadowOverlap)))}break;case"right":if(shadowShiftX-shadowOverlap>0){$box.css("left",(numb($box.css("left"))+shadowShiftX-shadowOverlap))}break;case"bottom":if(shadowShiftY-shadowOverlap>0){$box.css("top",(numb($box.css("top"))+shadowShiftY-shadowOverlap))}break;case"left":if(opts.shadowOffsetY+opts.shadowBlur-shadowOverlap>0){$box.css("left",(numb($box.css("left"))-(opts.shadowOffsetY+opts.shadowBlur-shadowOverlap)))}break}}drawIt.apply(ctx,[points]);ctx.fillStyle=opts.fill;if(opts.shadow){ctx.shadowOffsetX=opts.shadowOffsetX;ctx.shadowOffsetY=opts.shadowOffsetY;ctx.shadowBlur=opts.shadowBlur;ctx.shadowColor=opts.shadowColor}ctx.closePath();ctx.fill();if(opts.strokeWidth>0){ctx.shadowColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)";ctx.lineWidth=opts.strokeWidth;ctx.strokeStyle=opts.strokeStyle;ctx.beginPath();drawIt.apply(ctx,[points]);ctx.closePath();ctx.stroke()}opts.preShow.apply(this,[$box[0]]);$box.css({display:"none",visibility:"visible"});opts.showTip.apply(this,[$box[0]]);if(opts.overlay){var overlay=$('<div class="bt-overlay"></div>').css({position:"absolute",backgroundColor:"blue",top:top,left:left,width:width,height:height,opacity:".2"}).appendTo(offsetParent);$(this).data("overlay",overlay)}if((opts.ajaxPath!=null&&opts.ajaxCache==false)||ajaxTimeout){content=false}if(opts.clickAnywhereToClose){jQuery.bt.vars.clickAnywhereStack.push(this);$(document).click(jQuery.bt.docClick)}if(opts.closeWhenOthersOpen){jQuery.bt.vars.closeWhenOpenStack.push(this)}opts.postShow.apply(this,[$box[0]])};this.btOff=function(){var box=$(this).data("bt-box");opts.preHide.apply(this,[box]);var i=this;i.btCleanup=function(){var box=$(i).data("bt-box");var contentOrig=$(i).data("bt-content-orig");var overlay=$(i).data("bt-overlay");if(typeof box=="object"){$(box).remove();$(i).removeData("bt-box")}if(typeof contentOrig=="object"){var clones=$(contentOrig.original).data("bt-clones");$(contentOrig).data("bt-clones",arrayRemove(clones,contentOrig.clone))}if(typeof overlay=="object"){$(overlay).remove();$(i).removeData("bt-overlay")}jQuery.bt.vars.clickAnywhereStack=arrayRemove(jQuery.bt.vars.clickAnywhereStack,i);jQuery.bt.vars.closeWhenOpenStack=arrayRemove(jQuery.bt.vars.closeWhenOpenStack,i);$(i).removeClass("bt-active "+opts.activeClass);opts.postHide.apply(i)};opts.hideTip.apply(this,[box,i.btCleanup])};var refresh=this.btRefresh=function(){this.btOff();this.btOn()}});function drawIt(points){var strokeWidth=jQuery.bt.options.strokeWidth?jQuery.bt.options.strokeWidth:jQuery.bt.defaults.strokeWidth;this.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);for(i=1;i<points.length;i++){if(points[i-1].type=="arcStart"){this.quadraticCurveTo(round5(points[i].x,strokeWidth),round5(points[i].y,strokeWidth),round5(points[(i+1)%points.length].x,strokeWidth),round5(points[(i+1)%points.length].y,strokeWidth));i++}else{this.lineTo(round5(points[i].x,strokeWidth),round5(points[i].y,strokeWidth))}}}function round5(num,strokeWidth){var ret=num;strokeWidth=numb(strokeWidth);if(!(strokeWidth%2)){ret=Math.round(num-0.5)+0.5}return ret}function numb(num){return parseInt(num)||0}function arrayRemove(arr,elem){var x,newArr=new Array();for(x in arr){if(arr[x]!=elem){newArr.push(arr[x])}}return newArr}function shadowSupport(){try{var userAgent=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();if(/webkit/.test(userAgent)){return true}else{if(/gecko|mozilla/.test(userAgent)&&parseFloat(userAgent.match(/firefox\/(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)/)[1])>=3.1){return true}}}catch(err){}return false}function betweenPoint(point1,point2,dist){var y,x;if(point1.x==point2.x){y=point1.y<point2.y?point1.y+dist:point1.y-dist;return{x:point1.x,y:y}}else{if(point1.y==point2.y){x=point1.x<point2.x?point1.x+dist:point1.x-dist;return{x:x,y:point1.y}}}return false}function findIntersect(r1x1,r1y1,r1x2,r1y2,r2x1,r2y1,r2x2,r2y2){if(r2x1==r2x2){return findIntersectY(r1x1,r1y1,r1x2,r1y2,r2x1)}if(r2y1==r2y2){return findIntersectX(r1x1,r1y1,r1x2,r1y2,r2y1)}var r1m=(r1y1-r1y2)/(r1x1-r1x2);var r1b=r1y1-(r1m*r1x1);var r2m=(r2y1-r2y2)/(r2x1-r2x2);var r2b=r2y1-(r2m*r2x1);var x=(r2b-r1b)/(r1m-r2m);var y=r1m*x+r1b;return{x:x,y:y}}function findIntersectY(r1x1,r1y1,r1x2,r1y2,x){if(r1y1==r1y2){return{x:x,y:r1y1}}var r1m=(r1y1-r1y2)/(r1x1-r1x2);var r1b=r1y1-(r1m*r1x1);var y=r1m*x+r1b;return{x:x,y:y}}function findIntersectX(r1x1,r1y1,r1x2,r1y2,y){if(r1x1==r1x2){return{x:r1x1,y:y}}var r1m=(r1y1-r1y2)/(r1x1-r1x2);var r1b=r1y1-(r1m*r1x1);var x=(y-r1b)/r1m;return{x:x,y:y}}};jQuery.fn.btPosition=function(){function num(elem,prop){return elem[0]&&parseInt(jQuery.curCSS(elem[0],prop,true),10)||0}var left=0,top=0,results;if(this[0]){var offsetParent=this.offsetParent(),offset=this.offset(),parentOffset=/^body|html$/i.test(offsetParent[0].tagName)?{top:0,left:0}:offsetParent.offset();offset.top-=num(this,"marginTop");offset.left-=num(this,"marginLeft");parentOffset.top+=num(offsetParent,"borderTopWidth");parentOffset.left+=num(offsetParent,"borderLeftWidth");results={top:offset.top-parentOffset.top,left:offset.left-parentOffset.left}}return results};jQuery.fn.btOuterWidth=function(margin){function num(elem,prop){return elem[0]&&parseInt(jQuery.curCSS(elem[0],prop,true),10)||0}return this["innerWidth"]()+num(this,"borderLeftWidth")+num(this,"borderRightWidth")+(margin?num(this,"marginLeft")+num(this,"marginRight"):0)};jQuery.fn.btOn=function(){return this.each(function(index){if(jQuery.isFunction(this.btOn)){this.btOn()}})};jQuery.fn.btOff=function(){return this.each(function(index){if(jQuery.isFunction(this.btOff)){this.btOff()}})};jQuery.bt.vars={clickAnywhereStack:[],closeWhenOpenStack:[]};jQuery.bt.docClick=function(e){if(!e){var e=window.event}if(!$(e.target).parents().andSelf().filter(".bt-wrapper, .bt-active").length&&jQuery.bt.vars.clickAnywhereStack.length){$(jQuery.bt.vars.clickAnywhereStack).btOff();$(document).unbind("click",jQuery.bt.docClick)}};jQuery.bt.defaults={trigger:"hover",clickAnywhereToClose:true,closeWhenOthersOpen:false,shrinkToFit:false,width:"200px",padding:"10px",spikeGirth:10,spikeLength:15,overlap:0,overlay:false,killTitle:true,textzIndex:9999,boxzIndex:9998,wrapperzIndex:9997,offsetParent:null,positions:["most"],fill:"rgb(255, 255, 102)",windowMargin:10,strokeWidth:1,strokeStyle:"#000",cornerRadius:5,centerPointX:0.5,centerPointY:0.5,shadow:false,shadowOffsetX:2,shadowOffsetY:2,shadowBlur:3,shadowColor:"#000",shadowOverlap:false,noShadowOpts:{strokeStyle:"#999"},cssClass:"",cssStyles:{},activeClass:"bt-active",contentSelector:"$(this).attr('title')",ajaxPath:null,ajaxError:"<strong>ERROR:</strong> <em>%error</em>",ajaxLoading:"<blink>Loading...</blink>",ajaxData:{},ajaxType:"GET",ajaxCache:true,ajaxOpts:{},preBuild:function(){},preShow:function(box){},showTip:function(box){$(box).show()},postShow:function(box){},preHide:function(box){},hideTip:function(box,callback){$(box).hide();callback()},postHide:function(){},hoverIntentOpts:{interval:300,timeout:500}};jQuery.bt.options={}})(jQuery);
```